# How to display programmatically created custom options in admin order details

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart, programmatically, order-details

I created 4 programmatically custom options. It is successfully display in cart page and also make successful order. I created module for that. Here its code.

path : **vendor/addtocart/controller/index/index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Addtocart\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_session;
    protected $serializer;
    protected $ProductRepository;

    protected $_responseFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $ProductRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $PageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    array $data = []) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;

        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->_pageFactory = $PageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->product = $product; 
        $this->ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
        $this->_session = $session;    
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
      $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
      $productId =1;
      $id = $this->_session->getId();
      $additionalOptions['firstnamesku'] = [
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'value' => 'chirag',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['lnamesku'] = [
                'label' => 'Last Name',
                'value' => 'parmar',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['emailidsku'] = [
                'label' => 'Email ID',
                'value' => 'chirag@gmail.com',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['phonenosku'] = [
                'label' => 'Phone No',
                'value' => '1234567890',
            ];

      if(!$this->_session->isLoggedIn()){
      $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product
            );   
       }else{
            $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product
                    'customer_id'   =>$id
            );
    }           
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->ProductRepository->getById($productId);
    $_product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)); 
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
    //return $page;
    $message = "Product have been successfully added to your Shopping Cart.";
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message);
    $accUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($accUrl)->sendResponse();
    $this->setRefererUrl($accUrl);
  }
}
```

Now I hit this url : **domainname.com/addtocart**

Successfully add product to cart and redirect to cart page.

[image]

Placed order successsfully. Now also seen this order in **admin->sales-> orders**.

But the **problem** is I can not find this **custom options in order details**.

[image]

I also created observer for this. But not getting result as I want.

**Vendor\Addtocart\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="unique_name" instance="Vendor\Addtocart\Observer\OrderItemAdditionalOptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Vendor\Addtocart\Observer\OrderItemAdditionalOptions.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Addtocart\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderItemAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $quoteItems = [];

            // Map Quote Item with Quote Item Id
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItems[$quoteItem->getId()] = $quoteItem;
            }

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
                $quoteItemId = $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
                $quoteItem = $quoteItems[$quoteItemId];
                $additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
                //print_r($additionalOptions); exit("=======");


                if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
                    // Get Order Item's other options
                    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    // Set additional options to Order Item
                    $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // catch error if any
            echo 'Error!!: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I got error in this code. This code is just for information.

Anyone can help me to figured it out? Thanks in advance..

**Edit:-**

I saw that in database table "sales_order_item" fieldname "**product_options**"has this value :

> {"info_buyRequest":{"product":1,"qty":1}}

Now I create 2 custom option from adminside and check database for other product. I got following code. If I put this code in that order, than it will give some data which i want :

> {"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tMjM0L3N0cml2ZS1zaG91bGRlci1wYWNrLmh0bWw,","product":"2","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","item":"2","options":{"1":"cparmar2","2":"rkhatri2"},"qty":"1"},"options":[{"label":"colorbox","value":"cparmar2","print_value":"cparmar2","option_id":"1","option_type":"field","option_value":"cparmar2","custom_view":false},{"label":"sizebox","value":"rkhatri2","print_value":"rkhatri2","option_id":"2","option_type":"field","option_value":"rkhatri2","custom_view":false}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

> create Event: Vendor\Addtocart\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="quote_to_order" instance="Vendor\Addtocart\Observer\OrderItemAdditionalOptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and then create observer like this

> Vendor\Addtocart\Observer\OrderItemAdditionalOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Addtocart\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Unserialize\Unserialize;
use \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;



class OrderItemAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    protected $Unserialize;

    protected $Serializer;

    public function __construct(
        Unserialize $Unserialize,
        Json $Json
    ){
        $this->Unserialize = $Unserialize;
        $this->Serializer = $Json;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $quoteItems = [];

            // Map Quote Item with Quote Item Id
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItems[$quoteItem->getId()] = $quoteItem; //130
            }

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
                $quoteItemId = $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
                $quoteItem = $quoteItems[$quoteItemId];
                $additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
     // Get Order Item's other options
                    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    // Set additional options to Order Item
                   if($this->isSerialized($additionalOptions->getValue())){
                        $options['options'] = $this->Unserialize->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                   }else{
                    $options['options'] = $this->Serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                   }


                    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
            }
        }

        catch (\Exception $e) {
            // catch error if any
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    private function isSerialized($value)
    {
        return (boolean) preg_match('/^((s|i|d|b|a|O|C):|N;)/', $value);
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you. If it works please accept it.

Comment: Let me check it. @Ronak

Comment: And also run command bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: It works perfectly. I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot **$orderItem->save();**

Comment: i tried it but its not working. I think problem is with  $additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options');

Answer (score 0):

It will append option into the column(**product_options**) of table (**sales_order_item**) and it will show in admin,email and pdf.

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

$serialNo = 123456;

foreach($orderItems as $orderItem){

        $orderItemId = $orderItem->getItemId();
        $option = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
        $serialOptions[] = array('label' => "Serial No.",'value' => $serialNo);
        $option['options'] = $serialOptions;
        $orderItem->setProductOptions($option)->save(); 
}
```